# Azure Xplat CLI - Git repo

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

I am trying to create a Web App and storage account using Azure cli, and doing a continuous publishing on it. How to enable your web app local git repo from azure cli?

Comment: Your question misses important details, what you really want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can enable the local git deployment when you creating a web app in Azure-Cli.

Please try the following steps:

```
azure login
azure config mode asm
azure site create --git {your_site_name}
```

Meanwhile, you can use `azure site create -h` for the detailed option reference for the creation operation.